# SQL Server bulk insert and view behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have a table called A and a view on that table called A_View. A_View is a join which contains also other tables.

What will happen if:

**I exceute a huge query on A_View and at the same time, I perform a bulk insert on my table A**

- which query will be blocked from the database?
- do i see the data in the view directly after the load?

Or:

**I exceute a huge query on table A and at the same time, I perform a bulk insert on my table A**

- which query will be blocked from the database?

first come first serve?

Comment: It depends on isolation levels, locking, partitioning, and query hints.  The question is too broad.

Comment: Right, thanks Gordon. Let's say: no patitioning and standard mssql server configuration for my table and view.

Comment: As per my understandings,Say for example- Bulk insert has 1 lakh records for load and loading Process started. If we run the view now, it would give the number of records that are inserted at that instant of time.